# Dart flutter if-else body property

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I did the [Write Your First Flutter App, part 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#0) tutorial.

Let's consider this code, extracted from the application of the tutorial.

```
return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Saved Words'),
            ),
            body: ListView(children: divided),
          );
```

Why can't I write something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Saved Words'),
            ),
            body: () { if (true) {
              ListView(children: divided);
            }
            },
          );
```

Can't I put an If statement while I am defining a Widget property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. But have a look at the code below, this allows you to do essentially the same.

```
  return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Saved Words'),
        ),
        body: variable == 2 ? Container() : Center()
 );
```

Edit for clarification, the syntax goes:

bool evaluation ? if true : if false

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator:

```
body: _isTrue
        ? ListView(children: divided)
        : <some other widget>;
```